# "Request timed out" when makinng two HttpWebRequests to the same Java server from C# over .NET Compact

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, .net-cf-3.5, java-server

I have a client application running on C# on a .NETCF 3.5 device POSTing to a Java servlet located remotely. I am receiving a "Request Timed out" during my third HTTP POST to the same servlet. For example, if the servlet manages login to our Java server, the first two login attempts from the client would go through (same client device) and when I attempt the third one, it will return in a "Request timed out" exception from the server. I have noticed this happen always and I can't figure out the problem. I read that C# by default sends the Request 100 continue in the HTTP headers so I used the ServicePointManager to set the request 100 to false to no avail.

Here is the code that is throwing this error:

```
            serverUrl = url;
            string responseFromServer = "";
            try
            {
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
                int tmp = ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit;
                // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
                request.Method = "POST";
                // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.            
                byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(url);
                // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";                
                // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                request.Timeout = (50 * 100);
                request.Proxy = System.Net.GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();
                // Get the request stream.
                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                // Write the data to the request stream.
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                // Close the Stream object.
                dataStream.Close();
                // Get the response.
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                // Read the content.
                responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // Clean up the streams.
                reader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                response.Close();

                return responseFromServer;
            }
            catch (Exception WebExp)
            {
                Logging.Instance.Log(Logging.Levels.Error, "Error in DoPost while retrieving : "+url+ " " + WebExp.Message.ToString());
                Logging.Instance.Log(Logging.Levels.Error, WebExp.StackTrace.ToString());
                throw WebExp;
            }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I was just hammering my app with login/logouts to see if it worked and it failed when I logged in the second time (so the third HTTP POST) which lead me to investigate whether my logout mechanism on the server was broken or my POST on the client. This is why I am logging in multiple times, i know it makes little sense but its just a sort of a concentrated test to see where my POST is broken.

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour is due to wrong Exception handling regarding to the WebResponse. You have always to handle the response and close it. Otherwise the third attempt of HTTP Webrequest will fail with timeout which is limited by WinCE.

Following source code will be safe:

```
HttpWebResponse response = null;
try
{
    //...
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    //...
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // logging, etc.
    throw e;
}
finally
{
    if(response!=null)
    {
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to know! Can you share your source regarding the limitations of WinCE with WebRequests and Responses?